# Setting part of an array to zero efficiently

Tags: c++, arrays, memset

I am trying to reset an array of simple objects to zero, as shown below:

```
using Node = std::array<std::uint16_t, 256>;
using Array = std::array<Node, 4096>;

void reset_1(Array& a) {
  std::fill(std::begin(a), std::end(a), Node{});
}
    
void reset_2(Array& a) {
  a = {};
}

void reset_3(Array& a) {
  a.fill(Node{});
}
```

All these functions get the job done, but looking at the compiler explorer (using both Clang 10.0.1 and gcc 10.2), `reset_2` does it in one `memset`, while the other two do it in multiple chunks (same result using `std::fill_n`).

In my real case, I actually want to reset all nodes, except for the first one. This would lead me to write something like:

```
void reset_not_zero_1(Array& a) {
  std::fill(std::begin(a) + 1, std::end(a), Node{});
}
    
void reset_not_zero_2(Array& a) {
  std::memset(a.data() + 1, 0, sizeof(a) - sizeof(Node));
}
```

My question is: am I invoking some sort of undefined behavior with `reset_not_zero_2`? The array is trivially copyable, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: i would also consider this option: store the first element in `temp`, reset the whole array, assign `temp` to first element.

Comment: This is ok. `std::array` is just a c-style array wrapped in an objects to add all the copy-semantics and other convenient things to it.

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset)

> Converts the value ch to unsigned char and copies it into each of the
> first count characters of the object pointed to by dest. If the object
> is a potentially-overlapping subobject or is not TriviallyCopyable
> (e.g., scalar, C-compatible struct, or an array of trivially copyable
> type), the behavior is undefined. If count is greater than the size of
> the object pointed to by dest, the behavior is undefined.

So far so good.

assume another Node size is 14 but its alignas is 16

```
using Array = std::array<Node, 4096>;
```

size of 'a' would then be 16*4096 = 65536 as Node would force a padding of 2.

```
std::memset(a.data() + 1, 0, sizeof(a) - sizeof(Node));
```

This would then be 65536-14 out of 65536-16 bytes, which is not OK, asa it overwrites 2 bytes of the next data.

If on the other hand

```
sizeof(a) == a.size()*sizeof(a::value_type)
```

Then it should be OK.

Also if alignas force a larger sizeof it should also be OK.

Comment: `sizeof` always contains the padding.

Comment: @eerorika isn't that only for internal padding? as opposed to padding forced by alignas.

Comment: If alignment of  Node is 16, then beginning of two element of array of Node are 16 bytes apart. This distance is by definition what sizeof returns.

Comment: @eerorika I don't see any effect on sizeof for alignment on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Alignment but my compiler returns sizeof as the alignas if more restrictive than the members.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: am I invoking some sort of undefined behavior with reset_not_zero_2?

No. Seems fine to me.